Installing r package
I'm having difficulty installing chemmineOB. I was able to install biocmanager and chemmineR without much difficulty. I installed openbabel using brew and found that it exists in ~/local/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/ in my directories. It is version 3.1.0. I am running r version 4.4.0 and I have bioconductor version 3.19 (all current). I have been running:
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("ChemmineOB")

and I get:
ChemmineOB.cpp:1569:10: fatal error: 'openbabel/obutil.h' file not found
#include <openbabel/obutil.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [ChemmineOB.o] Error 1

I also get this additional output:
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see 'help("repositories", package = "BiocManager")' for details.
Replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/
Bioconductor version 3.19 (BiocManager 1.30.23), R 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Installing package(s) 'ChemmineOB'
Warning: downloaded length 0 != reported length 11310Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.19/data/annotation/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.4/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Warning: downloaded length 0 != reported length 11310Warning: cannot open URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.19/data/annotation/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.4/PACKAGES.gz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ChemmineOB’

I'm not sure why it won't recognize .obutil.h as this file exists in that directory.

Maybe this Bioconductor post will help.

I had checked this out the other day and continued to run into a few problems with it. Thanks for looking though!
